# Python Regex if there is a brace in string

Tags: python, regex

```
the co[njuring](media_title)
```

I want a regex to detect if a pattern like above exist.

Currently I have a regex that turns

```
line = Can I please eat at[  warunk upnormal](restaurant_name)

line = re.sub('\[\s*(.*?)\s*\]', r'[\1]', line)
line = re.sub(r'(\w)\[', r'\1 [', line)

Can I please eat at [warunk upnormal](restaurant_name)
```

Notice how there aren't any spaces which is good, and it creates a space char and brace ex. x[ to x [

What I want, is to **change** the above to regexes to not perform the change if there is a sentences like this

```
the co[njuring](media_title)
the co[njuring](media_title) and che[ese dog]s(food)
```

Notice how there is a brace in there. Basically, I want to know how can I improve these regexes to take this into account.

```
line = re.sub('\[\s*(.*?)\s*\]', r'[\1]', line)
line = re.sub(r'(\w)\[', r'\1 [', line)
```

Comment: These are called square brackets (or just brackets); braces are `{}`. Anyway, have you considered using other tools for this besides trying to handle the whole thing with one regex? If you're trying to normalize some Markdown input (what it looks like to me), then you probably really want to use a few regexes to *tokenize* the string (useful search term) and then re-assemble the desired output from the tokens.

Comment: Or use a markdown parser. See [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 0):

For the 2 patterns that you use, you could also use a single pattern with 2 capturing groups.

```
(\w)\[\s*(.*?)\s*\]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eGD6rD/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/abapdS)

In the replacement use the 2 capturing groups `\1 [\2]`

*Example code*

```
line = re.sub('(\w)\[\s*(.*?)\s*\]', r'\1 [\2]', line)
```

---

The different in the given format that I see is that there is an underscore present (instead of a brace) between the parenthesis `(restaurant_name)` and `(media_title)` vs `(food)`

If that is the  case, you can use a third capturing group, matching the value in parenthesis with at least a single underscore present, not at the start and not at the end.

```
(\w)\[\s*(.*?)\s*\](\([^_\s()]+(?:_[^_\s()]+)+\))
```

*Explanation*

- `(\w)` Capture **group 1**, match a word char
- `\[\s*` Match `[` and 0+ whitespace chars
- `(.*?)` Capture **group 2**, match any char except a newline non greedy
- `\s*\]`  Match 0+ whitespace chars and `]`
- `(` Capture **group 3**

  - `\(` Match `(`
  - `[^_\s()]+` Match 1+ times any char except an underscore, whitespace char or parenthesis
  - `(?:_[^_\s()]+)+` Repeat 1+ times the previous pattern with an underscore prepended
  - `\)` Match `)`
- `)` Close group

In the replacement use the 3 capturing groups `\1 [\2]\3`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v5XLU8/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/w8gkN2)

*Example code*

```
import re

regex = r"(\w)\[\s*(.*?)\s*\](\([^_\s()]+(?:_[^_\s()]+)+\))"

test_str = ("Can I please eat at[  warunk upnormal](restaurant_name)\n"
    "Can I please eat at[  warunk upnormal   ](restaurant_name)\n"
    "the co[njuring](media_title)\n"
    "the co[njuring](media_title) and che[ese dog]s(food)")

result = re.sub(regex, r"\1 [\2]\3", test_str)

if result:
    print (result)
```

*Output*

```
Can I please eat at [warunk upnormal](restaurant_name)
Can I please eat at [warunk upnormal](restaurant_name)
the co [njuring](media_title)
the co [njuring](media_title) and che[ese dog]s(food)
```